# Access ERROR: Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types.

Tags: sql, create-table

Oh yet another wonderful error from Access. This time I get the "Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types." message. This would seem like such a simple fix but I'm thoroughly confused as to why this message would pop up given my code:

Code for first table in which I'm trying to reference:

```
    CREATE TABLE ProgramSupervisor
    ( EmpNo                     CHAR (6) ,
      ProgramSupervisorNo       CHAR (6) ,
      TeamNo                    CHAR (3)        CONSTRAINT TeamNoRequired NOT NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT PKProgramSupervisor PRIMARY KEY (EmpNo , ProgramSupervisorNo) ,
      CONSTRAINT FKProgSupEmpNo FOREIGN KEY (EmpNo) REFERENCES Employee  )
```

Code for the second table that is referencing the first table:

```
    CREATE TABLE ISL
     (    ISLNo                   CHAR (6) ,
          ProgramSupervisorNo     CHAR (6) ,
          ISLName           VARCHAR (30)        CONSTRAINT ISLNameRequired NOT NULL,
          ISLStreet         VARCHAR (40)        CONSTRAINT ISLStreetRequired NOT NULL ,
          ISLCity           VARCHAR (30)        CONSTRAINT ISLCityRequired NOT NULL ,
          ISLState          CHAR (2)            CONSTRAINT ISLStateRequired NOT NULL ,
          ISLZip            CHAR (5)            CONSTRAINT ISLZipRequired NOT NULL,
          CONSTRAINT PKISL PRIMARY KEY (ISLNo) ,
          CONSTRAINT FKProgSupNo FOREIGN KEY (ProgramSupervisorNo) REFERENCES
          ProgramSupervisor  )
```

I'm trying to reference the PK ProgramSupervisorNo as a FK in my ISL table. Yet it gives me the above mentioned error when both fields in each table have a CHAR (6) data definition. I have no idea what to do and any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
CONSTRAINT FKProgSupNo FOREIGN KEY (ProgramSupervisorNo) REFERENCES
      ProgramSupervisor  )
```

you didn't specify the field in table ProgramSupervisor that you want to reference.  The error message is misleading.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. ProgramSupervisorNo is a foreign key referencing the PK ProgramSupervisorNo in the ProgramSupervisor table. I only have one PK ProgramSupervisorNo which is of the ProgramSupervisor table.

Comment: You still have to specify the table.  You might add another table later on with a field of that name, which would make your constraint ambiguous.

Comment: ProgramSupervisorNo is a field in ProgramSupervisor table (the table i'm referencing) . I specified the table in that constraint. Still not understanding how that involves the error message though. I've done this same exact setup in numerous tables and have never had this message pop up.

Comment: You might think you specified the table in the constraint, but I don't see it in the code you posted.  My answer was pasted from your question.  Do you see a table name anywhere?

Comment: Yes. ProgramSupervisor is the table name, which is the first block of code in my original post.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake, I misread it.  You did indeed specify the table name.  You didn't specify the field.  Answer edited.

Comment: Didn't I specify the field in the parenthesis after the FOREIGN KEY keyword? If you can, please provide the correct code in your reply as I'm still not quite understanding. Also, I just thought of something. Since the Program Supervisor is a child table and has a composite PK, is it required that I reference both PK's in the ISL table instead of just part of the PK (ProgramSupervisorNo)? Not sure if that makes a difference.